# SQL Server not working after upgrading windows 10 from windows 8.1

Tags: windows-10, sql-server, windows-10-upgrade, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

My Sql server 2012 has stopped working and now its not letting me login. Here is the error:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByGXmosQgHUqdGw4alFSb3otVkk/view?usp=sharing

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to 192.168.1.2.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> The network path was not found
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

please suggest what should I do

Comment: I have edited the question.  Please have a look

Comment: It not clear what your question is.  The current error doesn't indicate an inability to log into the server, the server on the other hand, cannot even be communicated with.

Comment: I have configured a Loop back adapter in order to connect my local database with an IP 192.168.1.2 with user name sa
its not working now

Comment: The error is specific.  There is nothing at that address that is even responding.  No attempts to access the server is being remade.  Verify all configuration to determine the cause of this behavior.

Comment: If you changed the computer name, then you won't be able to connect. You have to uninstall and install again.

Answer (score 3):

Was facing the same issue. Realized that Windows 10 had turned off the SQL Server Service.

To resolve, open 'services.msc' and start service of SQL Server ()

Answer (score 1):

Same error here but the connection problem happens only when using the computer name AND only from the server itself (clients can connect)

If instead of using "[servername]\[instancename]" you try to connect with "[serverip]\[instancename]" it works. That is the only workaround I found so far. A word from microsoft would be very appreciated.

moreover... it seems like the problem doesn't affect OSQL.

Answer (score -1):

probably because the service can not run Windows 10 memory compressor.
It also happened to me. Windows 10 version 10525.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version? Is there any workaround?